# R Plotting multiple groups of data in a single 3D plot

Tags: r

I am trying to plot different groups (e.g. A, B, C) of data in a 3-D plot where each group has a different colour (e.g. red, green, blue) by using scatterplot3d(). Currently, I am in position of creating 3-D plots for each of the data set. However, I cannot find a way to plot all the data in the same 3d plot by using different colours.

I would like to achieve something similar with the 2-D case where you can initially plot the first group by plot() and then add the rest of the groups with points().

Have anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: I used to do that but have found it more simpler to use ggplot2. I am no export so cannot your question. Take a look at this http://www.r-bloggers.com/turning-your-data-into-a-3d-chart/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `plot3d()` from rgl.
Since you provided no data, I made some up...

```
require(MASS)
mus <- 1:3
sigma <- diag(1, 3, 3)
mat <- mvrnorm(100, mus, sigma)

df <- data.frame(rbind(mvrnorm(100, mus, sigma),
            mvrnorm(100, 2*mus, sigma),
            mvrnorm(100, 3*mus, sigma)))

df$fac <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 100))

require(rgl)
plot3d(df$X1, df$X2, df$X3, col=as.numeric(df$fac))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Could you also change the character type of the plot? I tried pch but it did not work.

Comment: There is no `pch` argument in plot3d.